# Why am I not getting fluid to passenger rear brake

Tags: toyota, brakes, corolla, bleeding

After changing shoes,pads and rear cylinders, I started the brake bleed process with one brake not cooperating. The car is a 2000 Toyota Corolla front discs and rear drum. I started with the passenger rear with normal fluid drain. I then tried the drivers rear, and did not have any pressure at all. Never had this happen before.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely issue would be a clogged / deteriorated brake hose.  You could try to disconnect the brake hose from the brake line and see if it bleeds OK from the line.  If the fluid moves fine before the hose, the hose is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Were you bleeding the brakes from the line itself or the bleeder screw? I have seen faulty calipers that do not have a hole where the bleeder screw fits (the threaded hole). You can drill a hole yourself if you have a bit that is small enough to fit inside the threaded hole for the bleeder screw. That's what I did to mine and its working fine now.